# Jquery 'on' click for bootstrap model dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below on click function to handle the multiple bootstrap dialogues its working fine except dynamic elements  .

```
$('a[data-toggle="modal1"]').on('click', function(e) {};
```

So i changed on click function below  but it was not working .It gives empty object no errors

```
$('document.body').on('click','a[data-toggle="modal1"]', function(e) {};
```

Please suggest me what i missed in the that function.

Comment: if possible then create fiddle of your problem.

Comment: Try this $('document.body').on('click','class of anchor tag', function(e) {};

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but remove the quotes for document.body it working..

```
$(document.body).on('click','a[data-toggle="modal1"]', function(e) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on('click','a[data-toggle="modal1"]', function(e) {

/*Your logic goes here*/

};